# Gravity Forms One product selected

Tags: gravityforms

I use Gravity Forms with Product fields.
I have 6 different products with specific conditional logic for each one.
My customer has to choose only one product.
But by default, he can choose more than one product.

I try a lot of solutions without success.
--> With conditional logic (Show and Hide): If any product is Selected then Hide the others
--> With Populate Anything (From Gravity Wiz) and another form
--> With an alert when more than one product is selected, but I cannot have a "reset" button to unselect all

If anyone has an idea or could give me advice it will help so so much...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

Assuming your product types are radio button types, add "product_choice" to the 'Custom CSS Class' under the appearance tab for all 6 products.

Then add the following jquery script to the form (The easiest way is to use Gravity Forms Custom Javascript add on by Gravity Perks in my opinion)

```
$('.product_choice input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
  $('.product_choice input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

This will make it so that when a customer chooses one product, the others will deselect.

Comment: Just change "checkbox" in the script with "radio" and all ok... Thank you so much Rochelle